# Baking displacement map is missing,

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, mesh, texturing, displacement

Baking displacement map is missing.
[image]

Comment: there is no need to put an exclamation mark (!) at the end of every sentence. Questions are answered if someone knows how to answer. Adding a sense of urgency or desperation to the question does not get you a better or faster answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change from Cycles to Blender Render to enable the displacement baking.